# There might be a man in the middle attack against my server

Tags: authentication, ssh, man-in-the-middle

I have a little $7.20/y VPS, and the fingerprint for the ECDSA key has changed three times on me. This time, it happened shortly after I reinstalled the server (same day, in fact.) I always disable password login, and make sure you can't log in with passwords. After a while, I tried logging into my server, and I got the standard error telling me about the attack. I went ahead and disabled it, and was told that the host key for the domain I was logging into was different to the one for the IP. This nearly solidifies the idea of the attack by itself, but then I was prompted for a password. What tips do you have on stopping this? I always keep UFW enabled, and only allow SSH, and public/private key authentication is the only way to get into the server (without finding an exploit, ofc.)

Comment: Have you asked your hosting company? Maybe they shuffled your instance around and it broke the fingerprint.

Comment: Reinstalling the server likely creates a new host key, so it should have changed immediately after reinstallation.

Comment: The host key is generated upon installation of openssh-server. If you reinstalled the server, the host key will change unless you manually restore the one you had previously. With that in mind, nothing in your post sounds particularly unusual.

Comment: Exactly what @tlng05 said.

Comment: The IP address might have changed?

Answer (score 1):

When a change in the fingerprint of the key is detected, it can mean a few things:

- the key on the server genuinely changed - this is normal after an OS reinstallation and can happen after the sshd reinstallation
- someone is posing as your server, trying a MitM attack. This is possible [only with password-based authentication](http://www.gremwell.com/ssh-mitm-public-key-authentication).

Your comment about a password-based authentication suddenly appearing out of the blue would hint about the second case.

As a side note, there is no added value for someone who already hacked into your server to change the ssh key as it will raise an alert.